# Why does mutation make a react component non-reusable on it's own?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, higher-order-components

So I'm reading the react doc on HOC's (found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and there's this section:

"Resist the temptation to modify a component’s prototype (or otherwise mutate it) inside a HOC."

```
function logProps(InputComponent) {
  InputComponent.prototype.componentWillReceiveProps = function(nextProps) {
    console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
    console.log('Next props: ', nextProps);
  };
  // The fact that we're returning the original input is a hint that it has
  // been mutated.
  return InputComponent;
}

// EnhancedComponent will log whenever props are received
const EnhancedComponent = logProps(InputComponent);
```

"There are a few problems with this. One is that the input component cannot be reused separately from the enhanced component."

Why is the mutated input component not considered reusable while the wrapped component is?

Edit: If you think this section of the docs is just nonsense, I'd accept that as an answer if there's somewhat of an explanation.

Comment: Consider `logProps(InputComponent);` (intentionally ignoring return value) Now, even though `InputComponent` doesn't claim to implement the `logProps()` decorated interface, it still does because it's been mutated. i.e. `EnhancedComponent === InputComponent` is a bad thing, not a good thing.

Comment: Consider what happens when you use `logProps(InputComponent)` in one part of your application and `dontLogProps(InputComponent)` in another part of your application.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see, so by mutating componentA I break the contract that was set up in it's class definition and when I subsequently get handed componentA in some part of the app, I have no idea what I'm working with, right?  Basically the same problem with mixins it seems like.  Lmk if that sounds right to you.

Comment: Mixins are slightly less bad, because the convention for them is to exist in the same place as the declaration, so they are effectively considered as part of the contract even though they mutate the class definition. But otherwise your comparison is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying `InputComponent`'s prototype changes the definition of what an `InputComponent` *is*, and if affects every instance of `InputComponent`.

If you modify the prototype in a private, encapsulated way -- i.e., in a way that nobody knows about -- then nobody knows what an `InputComponent` is anymore, so they can't reliably use it.